# How to compare pose and position of two objects from rotation and translation matrix?

Tags: opengl, graphics, computer-vision

I have two 4*4 matrices representing the poses and positions of two objects in OpenGL.How to calculate the differences of orientation and origin of these objects.
Here is the matrix converted from OpenGL-Style matrix.

```
r1 r2 r3 t1
r4 r5 r6 t2
r7 r8 r9 t3
 0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say the two matrices are M1 and M2, which are applied to vectors from the right:

```
x1 = M1 * x
x2 = M2 * x
```

The "difference" between the two matrices can be defined as the matrix Md that needs to applied to x1 to get x2:

```
Md * x1 = x2
Md * (M1 * x) = M2 * x
```

To create this identity for all vectors x, Md needs to satisfy the equation:

```
Md * M1 = M2
```

To isolate Md in this equation, we multiply by the inverse of M1:

```
Md * M1 * inv(M1) = M2 * inv(M1)
```

Matrix multiplication is associative, so we can group the left side as:

```
Md * (M1 * inv(M1)) = M2 * inv(M1)
```

and the result for Md is:

```
Md = M2 * inv(M1)
```

So you can solve this with a 4x4 matrix inversion and a matrix multiplication.

An alternative is that you decompose the original matrixes into a rotation and a translation each, which are applied to vectors as:

```
x1 = R1 * x + t1
x2 = R2 * x + t2
```

where R1 and R2 are 3x3 matrices, t1 and t2 translation vectors. Following the same steps as before, but also writing the difference broken down into a rotation Rd and a translation td:

```
Rd * x1 + td = x2
Rd * (R1 * x + t1) + td = R2 * x + t2
Rd * R1 * x + Rd * t1 + td = R2 * x + t2
```

For the rotation parts of both sides to match, Rd needs to satisfy:

```
Rd * R1 = R2
```

Not surprisingly, the calculation of Rd looks very similar to Md above. As a simplification, we can take advantage of the fact that the inverse of a rotation is its transpose:

```
Rd = R2 * inv(R1)
Rd = R2 * transp(R1)
```

Now in the equation above, the translation parts also need to match, which gives us td:

```
Rd * t1 + td = t2
td = t2 - Rd * t1
```

In summary, you calculate the rotation matrix and translation vector of the difference as:

```
Rd = R2 * transp(R1)
td = t2 - Rd * t1
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will try what you said and then leave a comment.

Comment: I prefer the second method when consider my situation.
It seems that it works well when I calculate Rd.
But when there is an obvious difference of the orientation between
the two objects, td is NOT going to be (0,0,0) even through the objects share the same origin. So I just let td = t1-t2, as those two vectors are the center of the two objects,am I right?

Comment: Yeah, I think if you just want to know how far apart they are, `t2 - t1` would give you that. The reason it came out different in my calculation is that it's for the case where you wanted to apply the "difference" transformation. In that case, you would rotate first, which needs to be taken into account when translating.